# Retrieve ArrayLIst which is a value in HashMap

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, bundle

I have a `HashMap` `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Bundle>> hashMap` I am able to put values in the `HashMap` . And the hashmap is passed to the next class . Now how to get the `ArrayList` of `Bundle`  from `HashMap`. Any how I am using `Iterator` `Set` . Still I am not able to list the values of HashMap which is an arraylist.    This is actually am Message picker . And I have multiselection mode on using callback for listview. When I click on a sms list , I need to get some details and store it in a `hashmap` . There might be chance that a sms can have multiple recepinets. The `key` will be position .  I need to take all the values of the `HashMap` that is `ArrayList` into one single `ArrayList`. Say int the 0th position we have [0,[A,B]] ,[1,[C,D]]  , i want to create a new arraylist and store A , B, C, D in it.

Comment: Uhwell, using `.get()`... Why the question?

Comment: cant you look to the HashMap documentation?

Comment: Using `.get()`. Is that the question ?

Comment: This is a trick question, right?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a complete example:

```
public class Test {
    private final String value;

    public Test(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Test>> example = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Test>>();

        ArrayList<Test> test1 = new ArrayList<Test>();
        test1.add(new Test("HELLO"));

        ArrayList<Test> test2 = new ArrayList<Test>();
        test2.add(new Test("HELLO2"));

        example.put(1, test1);
        example.put(2, test2);

        // We get the second arraylist
        // Where 2 is the Integer we added in example.put(2, test2);
        ArrayList<Test> testExtracted = example.get(2); 

        System.out.println(testExtracted.get(0).value); // Prints HELLO2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like that

```
ArrayList<Bundle> value = hashMap.get(yourkey);
```

Comment: Key-type is `Integer`...